# Disambiguate molecule's bonds, angles or dihedral angles selection

Tags: computational-chemistry

I am working on a project where one of the goals is to store data from computational quantum chemistry calculations for later retrieval.

Currently, we are trying to store the outcomes of simple bond (or angle or dihedral angle) "scan jobs". The main problem we have is in finding a way to represent the scan coordinate that would be independent of the order of the atoms in a molecule.

As an example, given a simple $\ce{C-C}$ bond scan in $\ce{CH3CH2CH2CH3}$ molecule, we may define the scan coordinate using atom labels and their order in the molecule (where the order may be taken as the order of atoms in an xyz coordinate file) so that we know which $\ce{C-C}$ bond has been scanned.

However, that would only work if the order of atoms is kept the same. What if there are other scan jobs on the same molecule and the same $\ce{C-C}$ bond, but with different order of atoms. How could we define that $\ce{C-C}$ bond in an unambiguous way?

Our goal is to store the scan jobs in a distributed way and access them via a simple query that would define the molecule and the bond (or angle or dihedral angle) we want the scan data for.

I was thinking that maybe SMARTS strings would allow us to somehow describe the scan coordinate pattern we want to retrieve (e.g. two atoms for a bond or three atoms for an angle or four atoms for a dihedral angle). However, it is not yet clear how could I do that with SMARTS.

Another problem is that sometimes to disambiguate which bond (angle/dihedral) has been scanned one needs to provide extra context information about the bond chemical environment(certain functional groups near the bond atoms etc.). Any advice on how to define such scan coordinates will be welcome.

Comment: You definitely want to use SMARTS, likely with atom classes to define the atoms involved in the scan (e.g., c1c[cH:1][c:2](cc1)[C:3](=[O:4])O). Take a look at QCArchive's Torsion Drive notes: https://qcarchivetutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_examples/torsiondrive_datasets.html